# Spawn Failed problem publishing to Apple Store

Tags: nativescript

When we hit the button to do the final publish to Apple Store we get a "Spawn failed" error and cannot find out why.  Apple quite rightly say "it's not our problem as you're using someone else's tools" but that's not really helpful.  Anyone have any pointers on where to look.

Spawn failed.
, Error: Spawn failed.
    at CloudPublishService.getiOSError (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\nativescript-cloud\lib\services\cloud-publish-service.js:79:21)
    at CloudPublishService. (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\nativescript-cloud\lib\services\cloud-publish-service.js:96:29)
    at Generator.next ()
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming.nativescript-cli\extensions\node_modules\nativescript-cloud\lib\services\cloud-publish-service.js:4:58)

Comment: Might be a bug in nativescript-cloud, I'm going to file an issue there and link them to this issue.

Do you have two factor authentication on your apple account?

Issue filed: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cloud/issues/162

Comment: Hi yes we do have 2 factor authentication on.  We get past that page in SideKick.  I'll run another compile and note exactly which point it errors.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and just figured out what's going on. Because the error message is just a generic explosion while trying to get a real error message my fix may not fix your issue but here's what was going wrong for me:

I had two factor authentication on and I was trying to use the app-specific password that I generated for the nativescript appleId login. If you use the appleId main password then it will get past this error and then two factor authentication kicks in and asks for a number sent to your device, then it asks for the app-specific password

Comment: The "Spawn failed" message appears after the 2FA is successfully passed.

Comment: Did anyone figure this out? Spawn failed after the 2FA dialog, before the app-specific password? I had this before, then it randomly went away, and now it’s back with a vengeance. I may have to use my wife’s Mac now just to get the .ipa uploaded!

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you're entering the right credentials and the app-specific password, you may need to check if the Application Version (if you're using NativeScript Sidekick, it's in the Properties tab) is not equal to a version you've already published to the App Store. This fixed the 'Spawn failed' error for me.